# inoremap doesn't work

Tags: key-bindings, vimscript, plugin

#### Question summary

Currently I'm writing a pull request for [this](https://github.com/lfilho/cosco.vim) vim plugin which should set commas and semicolons automatically.
At the moment it looks if it should set a comma/semicolon/double point or not everytime the user presses any key . This makes the plugin a little bit heavy (in my opinion) so I want to call a function only when the user presses the return key and not for every key.

#### What I have now at this moment

This is currently in the plugin:

```
autocmd BufEnter * call cosco_autocmds#RefreshAutocmds()
```

This `cosco_autocmd#RefreshAutocmds()` enables the auto-setting for the current buffer:

```
autocmd TextChangedI <buffer> call cosco#AdaptCode()
```

Now I've tried this:

```
inoremap <CR> <C-O>:call cosco#AdaptCode()<CR>
```

But it looks like that the mapping doesn't call the function (you can try to add a `echom "Test"` in the `cosco#AdaptCode()` function). Do you have an idea how I can fix this?

#### Test it on your own

If you want to test it on your own, add [my pull request](https://github.com/TornaxO7/cosco.vim) to your plugin manager. For vim-plug it should be:

```
Plug 'TornaxO7/cosco.vim'
```

[This](https://github.com/TornaxO7/cosco.vim/blob/master/plugin/cosco.vim#L85) is the line where I want to put the `inoremap`. If you need more information, how this plugin works in general, take a look into its [CONTRIBUTING.md](https://github.com/TornaxO7/cosco.vim/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#plugin-explanation) file.

Comment: What do you mean by *"But it doesn't work"*? I do get this error `Error detected while processing TextChangedI Autocommands for "<buffer=1>"..function cosco#AdaptCode[41]..cosco_eval#ShouldNotSkip: line 56: E121: Undefined variable: g:cosco_ignore_comment_lines` but if I start with `:let g:cosco_ignore_comment_lines = 0` then it seems to work for me... I do seem to have the `TextChangedI` autocmd set, so it seems your fork isn't really removing that, is it?

Comment: One thing is you need your `<CR>` mapping to *also* produce an actual `<CR>`, so `inoremap <CR> <C-O>:call cosco#AdaptCode()<CR><CR>` is a start. It doesn't really work very well though, because it only adds the semi-colon for the preceding lines, so autoindent thinks the new line is a continuation line...

Comment: @filbranden first of all, thank you for the "bug report" I forgot to change the variable name. It should work now. 2. My fork *wants* to change this autocmd with the mapping. I'll edit my question. Thank you for the hints!

Comment: @filbranden It's my intention to add the semicolon/comma in the *previous* line, since this gives the opportunity to press the return key once, instead of leaving insertmode, going one line down and entering the insert mode again.